# Using vector or array?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, sorting, vector

I am writing string sorting and I couldn't decide whether I should use array or vector so that swap operation which I used in my algorithm is faster.
Assume I have a vector and array like that.

```
vector<string> vec;
string str[20];
```

Which one of the following swap operations would be faster, or they are equivalent?

```
vector[i].swap(vector[j]);
str[i].swap(str[j]);
```

Comment: How about profiling and seeing for yourself?

Comment: Neither; you should use `std::array<std::string, 20>` :-)

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the implementation, the OS and many many other factors? ...

Comment: @STATUS: the algorithmic complexity of most operations is [defined by the ISO](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) for all containers. An `std::vector` is equivalent to an array, except for its rich interface and safety! One might argue about indirection and such, but some operations are usually inlined. At the end, the best way to measure is by profiling it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are equivalent.  In fact, not only are they equivalent, they are **identical**, because in each case you are calling the exact same function:

```
basic_string::swap()
```

But, on to the larger question -- should you use an array or should you use a `vector`.  As a general rule of thumb, which I think I'd be hard pressed to find many legitimate exceptions to -- you should always use a `vector` by default in C++ unless you have a specific reason not to.  Speed will not be one of those reasons except in extraordinarily rare circumstances.

Comment: @Downvoter:  If you disagree with something I've said, please explain.

Comment: Not to disagree (because I agree wholeheartedly), but one reason to occasionally not use `vector` is to avoid order of initialization issues.  (This, of course, only affects variables with static lifetime.)  If you can use an array with static initializers, there can be no order of initialization issues.  And in C++03, C style arrays were the only containers for which the compiler would count the initializers, and dimension the array accordingly.

Comment: @James:  Excellent point.  I would categorize this as "a specific reason not to," but at the same time I would also categorize it as a code smell.

Comment: I actually use C style arrays quite a bit in these contexts.  In all cases, however: they are arrays of PODs (which can be allocated statically), they are at namespace scope (almost always unnamed namespace), and they are `const`.  In other words, they are laid out and initialized by the compiler, and never changed.  (Which means, of course, that I'm pretty certain that there can't be any memory management issues or such.)  It's a limited, very special use, but I wouldn't look askance  at it.

Comment: I think we're on the same page, here.  I have done the same as you, again for very limited special cases.  The reason I mentioned the code smell is to plant a seed for others reading this post that if you have order-of-initialization issues, it could be indicative of other flaws with the code's design.

Answer (score 1):

The swap operation should be more or less the same speed, *maybe* array is negligibly faster, but not the swap operation itself, but the way you access elements through `vector`.

You should probably look for non performance-related criteria here.

Comment: On what basis do you conclude that the array might be faster?

Comment: Because vector may be slower, as it adds a *very thin* layer on top of array. Like doing bound checks, etc. But once reference to the member is obtained, it's the same.

Comment: Vectors do no bounds checking.

Comment: That is, as far as the Standard is concerned.  Some specific implementations (such as MSVC) may add error- and bounds-checking functionality, but this is typically only added to debug builds, disabled in release builds and can even be disabled in debug builds.

Comment: Moreover, the Standard guarantees that A) the underlying storage is a contiguous memory block, like an array, and 2) `operator[]` is constant-time.

Comment: Never? Sure? Well, they will have to access the member of vector object pointing to the array before accessing array. And, finally, there is this word - "maybe" in my answer, so I'm quite happy with it being not any slower, which was the point of my answer anyway.

Comment: Yes, it is constant time, the question is only what is it in relation to array-based code constant time. Let me point out that besides this "maybe" word, I also used the word "negligibly" :)

Comment: I just wanted you to clarify the basis of your conclusions.  You've done so, so I thank you.  BTW, I didn't d/v your answer.  I strongly agree with your assertion that OP should " look for non performance-related criteria here".

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what made d/v do it, I'd appreciate comments, but honestly, I can live without ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Accessing elements in array will have a little bit better locality because when accessing element in array, you will apply offset to the address of the first element. When accessing element in vector, you will apply two offsets - one to get a pointer to array stored in vector class, and then another offset to get the element in that array. But this is not significant at all and compiler may (or even should) optimize this different away.

What in theory might slow you down here is a string comparison, and accessing contents of those strings. You see, `std::string` allocates its data on the heap, and if you get unlucky, every string's data will point to memory locations too far from each others. Given that contents of strings cannot fit in L1 cache and randomness of memory locations, prefetcher will fail to make data available to your code, and CPU will simply get stuck waiting for memory bus.

I'd start with more high-level optimizations. First, run a profiler to see what exactly is the bottleneck in your program. If that turns out to be sorting, I'd see if I can use different sorting algorithms (i.e. partial sort instead of a full sort). Then try to optimize memory access. And only then think whether I should use std::vector or not. What you are doing here I think is a premature optimization, which is no good.

Comment: -1 because: "std::vector, when accessing elements by index, does check if index is not out of bounds"  This is false.

Comment: See my comments on @Michael Krelin's answer.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Oh, crap. You are right - it doesn't, confused this bastard with Java's array!